# Synchronize information in same server with multiple ips

Tags: unix, ip-address

So i have a unix dedicated server and multiple ips. I am running a website on both ip address.

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
```

How do i make it so the files and folders on both ip addresses are synchronized? If i update index.php on the first ip, i want the change to be updated on the second ip. Any ideas?

Comment: In the immortal words of Charles Babbage, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

Comment: @mdpc if you assume a /24 it's not, but if it's a /23 it certainly is.

Comment: @Ben, welcome to [SF]! This is a community by System Administrators, for System Administrator (et al) only. You should contact your hosting provider for questions like this. For more details on [SF] please see the [FAQ] and [ASK]. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris Erm, doesn't look like the OP *has* a hosting provider unless you want to say apache/nginx is

Comment: @TheLQ Guessing by him using the term "Unix dedicated server" I'm certain he purchased a plan through a hosting provider. If he was running Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc on his own box he would have used the specific operating system name and wouldn't call it a *dedicated* server.

Answer (score 4):

Just make your webserver serves the same content for both IPs.

Comment: Yep. Nothing tricky here. Move along.

Comment: @mikeyB, how do i make my webserver serve the same content? What is the process for that?

Comment: You have two IPs on the same server. Just configure your web server (apache? nginx?) to answer of both IPs with the same virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the same server, and use the same web server, then you are synchronized.

Comment: Unless he has both IPs pointing to different site roots for some reason.